# How to fix JButton Location

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager

Previously I have asked a question about this program and I fixed it with you people. Now I have created new panel on the first panel which is containing the game of shapes. So I tried to set JButton on the new panel. But I cannot change the location of Jbuttons.
I am trying to set center of new panel.I have tried already FLowLayout(), BorderLayout() and setBounds(); Something is going wrong.

Previous questions; [How to move JFrame shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30954570/how-to-move-jframe-shape/30954808#30954808)

```
public class myshapestry extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

JFrame frame=new JFrame("Deneme");

 Startthegame panelstart= new Startthegame();
Container l ;

JLabel statusbar = new JLabel("default");
static JButton start;
static JButton exit;

 myshapestry() {

     l=this.getContentPane();
     this.setLayout(null);

     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.pack();
     frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

     frame.add(panelstart);
     frame.add(statusbar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(getPreferredSize());

       start = new JButton("Start");
       exit = new JButton("Exit");


       panelstart.add(start);
       panelstart.add(exit);




    }

 public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
       return new  Dimension(500,600);
   }

   public static void main (String args[]){
       myshapestry tr=new myshapestry();
       tr.setTitle("Game of Shapes");

    } 

   public class Startthegame extends JPanel {

   }







   }
```

Comment: If it is a continuation of previous question add that link in the question

Comment: use `panelstart.add(start, BorderLayout.CENTER);`

Comment: I have tried already but I didt get correct result

Comment: You're creating two instance of `JFrame`, which is very confusing, drop the `extends JFrame`.  `static` is not your friend, try and avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're extending from `JFrame`, but creating a new instance of `JFrame` within the class and interacting with both, which is just confusing the issues.  Start by getting rid of `extends JFrame`, you're not adding any new functionality to the class and it's just locking you into a single use case

`static` is not your friend and you should avoid using it where possible.  In this case, you can move the buttons to the `Startthegame`.  This is basic OO principle of isolation responsibility to units of work.

To get the buttons to center horizontally and vertically within the container, you can use a `GridBagLayout`

```
public class Startthegame extends JPanel {

    private JButton start;
    private JButton exit;

    public Startthegame() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        start = new JButton("Start");
        exit = new JButton("Exit");

        add(start);
        add(exit);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(500, 600);
    }

}
```

You should also call `setVisible` AFTER you've established the basic UI, otherwise you could end up within components not been displayed

For example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class MyShapesTry {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Deneme");

    Startthegame panelstart = new Startthegame();
    Container l;

    JLabel statusbar = new JLabel("default");

    public MyShapesTry() {

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(panelstart);
        frame.add(statusbar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                MyShapesTry tr = new MyShapesTry();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Okey, Thank you so much, I agree with you until main class. In main class I am getting the errors. the error is contains                                                        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

Comment: I am using JavaSe 1.7

Comment: Well, multi-catch is a feature of 1.7.  What's the exact error

Comment: Can you explain this block?  EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

Comment: Sounds like either your not importing the right exceptions or you're compiling to a version of Java below 1.7.  The `invokeLater` block is associated with [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)